# Reading empty AWS instance user data in Php causes Nginx error

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, nginx

I'm constantly getting this error in the *Nginx* logs:

```
FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://instance-data/latest/user-data): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found
```

The reason is that `http://instance-data/latest/user-data` is the *AWS* instance user data which is empty for this server.

How can I still read `user-data` in *PHP*, even if it is empty, without getting the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A short commit:

```
@file_get_contents("http://instance-data/latest/user-data");
```